# How to prevent unnecessary updates

Tags: updates

Update manager keeps wanting to install updates for LP-PPA-libreoffice / office productivity suite language packages

```
Afrikaans Assamese Bengali Breton ............. Zulu
```

I deactivate each language that I dont need in the click box, but they come back again the next day

How do I instruct Update Manager that the only languages that I need are Luxembourgish, German, French and English?

Comment: where exactly do you untick them?

Comment: @Jacob Vlijn asked Q. where I tick them?    A. In 12.04, top right hand corner of screen, "Updates available" leads to "Update Manager" which says "Software updates are available for this computer ...  27 updates have been selected ... 56.7 Mb will be downloaded"         Then in that very application theres a window with lots of lines and a tick box for each line. So I deactivate the tick for Afrikaans, for Assamese etc etc. Now done that three times ...

Comment: @Jacob Vlijn said "Let me know if you manage"
Perfect! And for those who come the same way, here are the other languages removed besides those mentioned above
english_southafrican, Gujarati, Hindi, Malayalam, Marathi, Ndbele, Northern_sotho, Oriya, Punjabi, Swazi, Southern_sotho, Tamil, Telugu, Tswana, Tsonga, Venda, Xhosa
Very many thanks for quick and helpful reply

Comment: @Jacob Vlijn said Q. "would you mind"  A. Please do! For a comprehensive answer perhaps you could comment whether to remove (which I did) or completely remove (which looked a bit dangerous) && also whether to remove the fonts which come up with some of the searches (I did not remove fonts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A package only gets updates if it is installed, so if the languages are updated, they must be installed somehow. To manage installed packages in a detailed way, Synaptic is a convenient tool. You can install Synaptic from the Software Center (or by the command `sudo apt-get install synaptic`). Then, in Synaptic, search for the packages and remove them if you are sure you don't need them.

#### Keeping the current version of a package

You can also tell update manager to keep the current version of a package if for some reason you'd prefer that, or if you are unsure. To do that, select the package you'd like to "fixate", choose "Package" from the menu, in the dropdown menu "Force version".

[image]

See also [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) to hold packages of a certain version (especially the "Introduction to Holding Packages" - section)

Comment: synaptic don't hold the app from upgrading, and follow the link, I found an "Introduction to Holding Packages", that for hold packages, rather than hold an app which I'm mentioning in.