# How to keep an app not to upgrade while others still be upgraded normally?

Tags: upgrade

My platform: U 14,04 LTS.

A problem with the modemmanger 1.0, that impossible to execute a connection via mobile broadband.
Now I have to downgrade the modemmanager by version 0.5.2.
Every perform

> apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

the system will upgrade all new version package, of course also the modemmanager.

How to keep only the modemmanger staying not upgrade?

Comment: You'll find it in this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/556149/72216

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm: 
synaptic don't hold the app from upgrading, and follow the link, I found an "Introduction to Holding Packages", that for hold packages, rather than hold an app which I'm mentioning in.

Comment: It really should work, did you run `sudo apt-get` update and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`? unless it is updated by its own updater. That seems not the case, since you mentioned it was updated by `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: I tried. either sudo apt-get update, then apt-get upgrade, and apt-get update && apt-get upgrade, it's the same.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm: You are right. I'm wrong, there was some mistakes, the package's hold now.

Comment: Perfect! Glad it works.